# IV changes the sign of exogenous variable

Tags: bias, instrumental-variables, probit, endogeneity

After implementing an IV probit model, the signs of many exogenous covariates' coefficients have been flipped, compared to those in the baseline probit model. These signs are now at odds with the past literature. I originally thought the IV approach would only significantly impact the coefficient estimates of the endogenous variables. What does this indicate? Is it because my instrument is not valid?

Comment: I think it is a common misconception that if only one RHS variable is correlated with the error, that the other coefficients are still consistently estimated. This will only be true if the endogenous variable is uncorrelated with the other included variables. So it's not surprising to me that this happens, especially in a nonlinear model, once you fix the endogeneity issue. I do not know what that implies about instrument validity. I would also look at the CIs here when comparing rather than just the point estimates. If there is substantial overlap, I would be less worried.

Comment: Thanks very much for your response, Dimitriy! This is really helpful. If you don't mind, could you explain what "Cls" indicates? Because I am not quite familiar with the econometrics jargons.  In response to your comment, I suppose you meant multicollinearity? I have run a simple OLS with all variables (including IVs) added in, and I found no multicollinearity issue existing between my endogenous and exogenous variables, using the VIF command in Stata.

Comment: I meant confidence intervals. Multicollinearity is not what I have in mind, but smearing. William Greene has a discussion of this in his econometrics time.

Comment: Thanks very much for your comment, Dimitriy. This helps a lot. So, will this issue induce any inconsistency issue, which will undermine my research design?

Comment: Unfortunately that is not something I can answer definitively.

Comment: I think it would be good to clarify what literature means more precisely. Are these previous exogenous effects credibly estimated or do they come from theory? Are they pairwise correlations or do they entail holding the other variables constant? For example, the price of race horses is positively related to the number of races won and with total winnings individually. Controlling for winnings, the races coefficient can become negative since it now corresponds to requiring more races to win the same amount of money.

Comment: Finally, how different are the literature estimates in magnitude and statistical significance. If one is a negative epsilon and one is positive epsilon and both have huge errors bars, I would be less concerned.

Comment: Thank you very much for the comment, Dimitriy! Sorry for being unclear about my statement. The past literature has credibly estimated the impact of, say, income, on the stock market participation, which is at odds with my findings. But I suppose this could be attributed to the difference in the definition of stock market, as I only considered the stocks that directly held. Your comment is very helpful!

Comment: If you don't mind, Dimitriy, may I ask another question: when I employing IV Probit model, should I make inference regarding the coefficient estimate or the marginal effects? because I have a discrepancy between the results generated by these two approaches.

Comment: I think that generally [should not happen](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/124935/7071) since standard normal CDF is monotonic, unless you have interactions. I think this is best left for another question, where you show code and output. You can rename the variables and multiply things by a constant if you are reluctant to show actual results.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete answer, but I thought I would organize some of my suggestions from the comments and give an empirical example of sign reversal, and two simulation examples that give the intuition for why sign reversal is not not necessarily a problem.

I think it is a common misconception that if only one RHS variable is correlated with the error, that the other coefficients are still consistently estimated. This will only be true if the endogenous variable is uncorrelated with the other included variables. So it's not surprising to me that this happens, especially in a nonlinear model, once you fix the endogeneity issue. I don't think that applies anything about instrument validity.

Here is an example where we want to estimate the effect of household income on supplemental insurance. This is a type of private health insurance plans sold to supplement Medicare in the United States. Medicare is primarily provides health insurance for Americans aged 65 and older, but also some disabled or very sick people. It is "borrowed" from Cameron and Trivedi's [MUS book](https://cameron.econ.ucdavis.edu/musbook/mus.html).

Note that the coefficient on White is negative in the baseline `probit` but become positive in the `ivprobit`:

```
. use "http://cameron.econ.ucdavis.edu/musbook/mus14data.dta", clear

. generate linc = log(hhincome)
(9 missing values generated)

. global xlist2 female age age2 educyear married hisp white chronic adl hstatusg

. global ivlist2 retire sretire

. probit ins linc $xlist2, nolog

Probit regression                               Number of obs     =      3,197
                                                LR chi2(11)       =     403.86
                                                Prob > chi2       =     0.0000
Log likelihood = -1933.4275                     Pseudo R2         =     0.0946

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
         ins |      Coef.   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
        linc |   .3466893   .0341499    10.15   0.000     .2797567    .4136219
      female |  -.0815374   .0511504    -1.59   0.111    -.1817904    .0187156
         age |   .1162879   .1221709     0.95   0.341    -.1231627    .3557384
        age2 |  -.0009395   .0009061    -1.04   0.300    -.0027153    .0008363
    educyear |   .0464387   .0089404     5.19   0.000     .0289159    .0639616
     married |   .1044152   .0640169     1.63   0.103    -.0210556    .2298859
        hisp |  -.3977334   .1140795    -3.49   0.000     -.621325   -.1741418
       white |  -.0418296   .0667783    -0.63   0.531    -.1727127    .0890535
     chronic |   .0472903   .0189362     2.50   0.013     .0101759    .0844047
         adl |  -.0945039   .0357786    -2.64   0.008    -.1646286   -.0243791
    hstatusg |   .1138708   .0639877     1.78   0.075    -.0115429    .2392845
       _cons |  -5.744548   4.114725    -1.40   0.163    -13.80926    2.320165
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. ivprobit ins $xlist2 (linc = $ivlist2), nolog 

Probit model with endogenous regressors         Number of obs     =      3,197
                                                Wald chi2(11)     =     354.58
Log likelihood = -5407.7151                     Prob > chi2       =     0.0000

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                   |      Coef.   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
              linc |  -.5338252   .3726921    -1.43   0.152    -1.264288    .1966379
            female |  -.1394072   .0495162    -2.82   0.005    -.2364571   -.0423572
               age |   .2862293   .1240301     2.31   0.021     .0431347    .5293238
              age2 |  -.0021472    .000908    -2.36   0.018    -.0039269   -.0003675
          educyear |   .1136881   .0231877     4.90   0.000     .0682411    .1591351
           married |   .7058309   .2303767     3.06   0.002      .254301    1.157361
              hisp |  -.5094514   .1020497    -4.99   0.000    -.7094651   -.3094378
             white |   .1563454    .100883     1.55   0.121    -.0413817    .3540726
           chronic |   .0061939   .0266342     0.23   0.816    -.0460082     .058396
               adl |  -.1347664   .0330215    -4.08   0.000    -.1994873   -.0700456
          hstatusg |   .2341789   .0688939     3.40   0.001     .0991493    .3692085
             _cons |  -10.00787   3.907857    -2.56   0.010    -17.66713   -2.348612
-------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
 corr(e.linc,e.ins)|   .5879559   .2267331                     -.0046375    .8749261
         sd(e.linc)|   .7177787   .0089768                      .7003984    .7355902
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Instrumented:  linc
Instruments:   female age age2 educyear married hisp white chronic adl hstatusg
               retire sretire
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Wald test of exogeneity (corr = 0): chi2(1) = 3.79        Prob > chi2 = 0.0516
```

One possible response is to say that neither one is significant and leave it there. You should probably do this in terms of average marginal effects with `margins, dydx(white)`, rather than index function coefficients. For probit, this means -1.4 percentage points less likely and for the `biprobit` it is +16.5 percentage points:

```
. qui probit ins linc $xlist2, nolog

. margins, dydx(white)

Average marginal effects                        Number of obs     =      3,197
Model VCE    : OIM

Expression   : Pr(ins), predict()
dy/dx w.r.t. : white

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |            Delta-method
             |      dy/dx   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
       white |  -.0143965   .0229799    -0.63   0.531    -.0594363    .0306432
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. qui ivprobit ins $xlist2 (linc = $ivlist2), nolog first

. margins, dydx(white)

Average marginal effects                        Number of obs     =      3,197
Model VCE    : OIM

Expression   : Fitted values, predict()
dy/dx w.r.t. : white

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |            Delta-method
             |      dy/dx   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
       white |   .1563454    .100883     1.55   0.121    -.0413817    .3540726
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

You can also appeal to the logic above to argue that this is does not mean that White is endogenous (also see simulation below).

You can also argue that if previous research on White insurance take-up did not adjust the effect for HH income at all or correctly, that could explain the difference in sign now. For example, the price of race horses is positively related to the number of races won and with total winnings, individually. Controlling for winnings, the races coefficient can become negative since it now corresponds to requiring more races to win the same amount of money. Here it is tougher to come up with an intuitive `ceteris paribus` explanation, but you problem might be different. In general, the bivariate intuitions about sign that come from previous work and theory are trickier when you have lots of covariates, because they are not always the same comparison. [This paper](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/%7Egelman/stuff_for_blog/oh_no_I_got_the_wrong_sign.pdf) by Peter Kennedy covers some of the other cases.

You could also argue that own and spouse retirement status are bad instruments, because they probably alter supplemental insurance buying through channels other than HH income, perhaps through health.

Here are some simulation examples showing the "smearing bias" that can happen when you have an exogenous variable that is correlated with an endogenous one and how that can alter the sign on the exogenous variable when the endogeneity is fixed. I did the linear IV case first, and then the control function version since that is more involved:

```
. /* Linear Example */
. set seed 07202020

. matrix C = (1, .25, .8 \ .25,  1, 0 \ .8, 0, 1)

. drawnorm x c u, n(10000) corr(C) clear
(obs 10,000)

. gen e = rnormal()

. gen y = 1 - 2*x + 0.5*c + 4.66*u + e 

. gen E = 4.66*u + e 

. corr x u c E
(obs=10,000)

             |        x        u        c        E
-------------+------------------------------------
           x |   1.0000
           u |   0.8038   1.0000
           c |   0.2422  -0.0055   1.0000
           E |   0.7877   0.9777  -0.0034   1.0000


. 
. /* fabricate an IV and solve things */
. reg x u

      Source |       SS           df       MS      Number of obs   =    10,000
-------------+----------------------------------   F(1, 9998)      =  18250.83
       Model |  6461.11847         1  6461.11847   Prob > F        =    0.0000
    Residual |  3539.46983     9,998  .354017787   R-squared       =    0.6461
-------------+----------------------------------   Adj R-squared   =    0.6460
       Total |  10000.5883     9,999  1.00015885   Root MSE        =    .59499

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
           x |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
           u |   .8022365   .0059383   135.10   0.000     .7905963    .8138768
       _cons |  -.0031226     .00595    -0.52   0.600    -.0147857    .0085406
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. predict z, resid

. replace z = z + rnormal()
(10,000 real changes made)

. reg y x c u       // true DGP

      Source |       SS           df       MS      Number of obs   =    10,000
-------------+----------------------------------   F(3, 9996)      =  34830.25
       Model |  104726.904         3   34908.968   Prob > F        =    0.0000
    Residual |  10018.5921     9,996  1.00226012   R-squared       =    0.9127
-------------+----------------------------------   Adj R-squared   =    0.9127
       Total |  114745.496     9,999  11.4756972   Root MSE        =    1.0011

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
           y |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
           x |  -1.978855    .018491  -107.02   0.000    -2.015102   -1.942609
           c |   .5040411    .010988    45.87   0.000     .4825024    .5255798
           u |   4.637909   .0179062   259.01   0.000     4.602809    4.673008
       _cons |   .9775556   .0100116    97.64   0.000     .9579308    .9971804
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. reg y x c         // baseline spec (omit u)

      Source |       SS           df       MS      Number of obs   =    10,000
-------------+----------------------------------   F(2, 9997)      =   2425.47
       Model |  37488.3041         2   18744.152   Prob > F        =    0.0000
    Residual |  77257.1921     9,997  7.72803762   R-squared       =    0.3267
-------------+----------------------------------   Adj R-squared   =    0.3266
       Total |  114745.496     9,999  11.4756972   Root MSE        =    2.7799

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
           y |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
           x |   1.995542   .0286515    69.65   0.000      1.93938    2.051705
           c |  -.4828779   .0286182   -16.87   0.000    -.5389752   -.4267805
       _cons |   .9864041   .0278001    35.48   0.000     .9319103    1.040898
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. ivreg y (x=z) c   // fix with IV

Instrumental variables (2SLS) regression

      Source |       SS           df       MS      Number of obs   =    10,000
-------------+----------------------------------   F(2, 9997)      =     60.92
       Model | -114035.469         2 -57017.7343   Prob > F        =    0.0000
    Residual |  228780.965     9,997   22.884962   R-squared       =         .
-------------+----------------------------------   Adj R-squared   =         .
       Total |  114745.496     9,999  11.4756972   Root MSE        =    4.7838

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
           y |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
           x |  -2.016389   .1826737   -11.04   0.000    -2.374466   -1.658311
           c |   .4876413   .0650832     7.49   0.000     .3600652    .6152174
       _cons |   .9584056   .0478553    20.03   0.000     .8645995    1.052212
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Instrumented:  x
Instruments:   c z
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. 
. /* IV Probit Simulation: control function version */
. set seed 07232020

. matrix sigma = (1,-.25\-.25,1)

. drawnorm e1 e2, n(10000) corr(sigma) clear
(obs 10,000)

. matrix C = (1,-.25\-.25,  1)

. drawnorm x1 x2, n(10000) corr(C)

. gen y2 = x2 + x1 + e2

. gen y1star = 1 + .05*y2 - .01*x2 + e1  

. gen y1 = cond(y1star >= 1,1,0)

. corr x2 y2 e1
(obs=10,000)

             |       x2       y2       e1
-------------+---------------------------
          x2 |   1.0000
          y2 |   0.4716   1.0000
          e1 |  -0.0128  -0.1540   1.0000


. probit y1 y2 x2, nolog

Probit regression                               Number of obs     =     10,000
                                                LR chi2(2)        =      76.22
                                                Prob > chi2       =     0.0000
Log likelihood =  -6893.103                     Pseudo R2         =     0.0055

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
          y1 |      Coef.   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
          y2 |  -.0775504   .0090042    -8.61   0.000    -.0951983   -.0599025
          x2 |   .0747156   .0143114     5.22   0.000     .0466658    .1027655
       _cons |   .0103127   .0125617     0.82   0.412    -.0143077    .0349331
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. ivprobit y1 (y2=x1) x2, nolog

Probit model with endogenous regressors         Number of obs     =     10,000
                                                Wald chi2(2)      =      18.14
Log likelihood = -20957.715                     Prob > chi2       =     0.0001

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                |      Coef.   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
----------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
             y2 |   .0509049   .0125527     4.06   0.000     .0263021    .0755076
             x2 |  -.0221555   .0157077    -1.41   0.158    -.0529419     .008631
          _cons |   .0081544   .0124891     0.65   0.514    -.0163237    .0326325
----------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
 corr(e.y2,e.y1)|  -.2502787   .0167809                     -.2828692    -.217111
        sd(e.y2)|   .9977357   .0070551                      .9840034     1.01166
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Instrumented:  y2
Instruments:   x2 x1
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Wald test of exogeneity (corr = 0): chi2(1) = 204.02      Prob > chi2 = 0.0000
```

---

**Stata Code:**

```
cls
use "http://cameron.econ.ucdavis.edu/musbook/mus14data.dta", clear
generate linc = log(hhincome)
global xlist2 female age age2 educyear married hisp white chronic adl hstatusg
global ivlist2 retire sretire
probit ins linc $xlist2, nolog
margins, dydx(white)
ivprobit ins $xlist2 (linc = $ivlist2), nolog first
margins, dydx(white)


/* Linear Example */
set seed 07202020
matrix C = (1, .25, .8 \ .25,  1, 0 \ .8, 0, 1)
drawnorm x c u, n(10000) corr(C) clear
gen e = rnormal()
gen y = 1 - 2*x + 0.5*c + 4.66*u + e 
gen E = 4.66*u + e 
corr x u c E

/* fabricate an IV and solve things */
reg x u
predict z, resid
replace z = z + rnormal()
reg y x c u       // true DGP
reg y x c         // baseline spec (omit u)
ivreg y (x=z) c   // fix with IV

/* IV Probit Simulation: control function version */
set seed 07232020
matrix sigma = (1,-.25\-.25,1)
drawnorm e1 e2, n(10000) corr(sigma) clear
matrix C = (1,-.25\-.25,  1)
drawnorm x1 x2, n(10000) corr(C)
gen y2 = x2 + x1 + e2
gen y1star = 1 + .05*y2 - .01*x2 + e1  
gen y1 = cond(y1star >= 1,1,0)
corr x2 y2 e1
probit y1 y2 x2, nolog
ivprobit y1 (y2=x1) x2, nolog
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Dimitriy! This is a very thorough answer. I've found it very helpful and I'm sure other people will too. Regarding my own research, I didn't find disproportionately high correlations among variables, so I'm more inclined to use the "endogeneity" explanation.